# How to catch GraphQL request errors status via react-query `useQuery`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-query

I want to implement a `retry` on failed queries. I'm using `react-query`'s `QueryClient` to handle queries with `GraphQL`. I can't find any good example online on how to handle `GraphQL` query errors via `react-query`. With the traditional RESTful request, we can handle request errors, e.g if `req.status` is `400` then do something. But with GraphQL I can't seem to emulate that. I'm not an expert in GraphQL, so I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Many Thanks

**REST**

```
import { QueryCache, QueryClient } from 'react-query`;

export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retry: (failureCount, error) => {
       return error.statusCode === 404 && failureCount <= 3 ? true : false;
      },
    }
  },
});
```

**GraphQL**

```
import { QueryCache, QueryClient } from 'react-query`;

export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retry: (failureCount, error) => {
       // This retry method is not called at all with GraphQL...
       console.log('ERR:::', error);
       return error.statusCode === 404 && failureCount <= 3 ? true : false;
      },
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: what are you using to make the graphQL request? It is important that a rejected Promise is returned so that react-query knows about errors and properly kicks off retries.

Comment: @TkDodo We're using AWS Amplify api to do request. And on the backend AWS AppSync with Lamda.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply provide a number to indicate how many retry attempts you want react-query to make.

```js
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retry: 3, // react-query will retry a failed request up to 3 times
    }
  },
});
```

There are other useful options to configure how errors and refetching works: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/useQuery